# How to create and set a new instance of class in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a class and I need to set a new instance of this class in XAML?
Can someone has an idea for this?

Comment: Read about Custom Controls in WPF.

Answer (score 3):

First add this:

```
xmlns:yc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

Then in the `Window.Resources` you can a new instance of the class like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:yc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <yc:Class1 x:Key="myInstance" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    ....
</Grid>
```

Change the `WpfApplication1` to the name of your project.